# Run JS link file on just 1 web part

Tags: web-part, jslink, databind

I have a page with 2 web parts. the 2 web parts are the same list just imported in different views. i have added a JS link file to 1 of the web parts using the edit web part properties miscellaneous field.

The problem is the js link file affects both web parts. where i only want it to affect 1 webpart. I know i can tick the server render option in the web part properties of the web part  i don't want to be affected by the js link file, but i would like to be able to include this in my code instead. i have tried using the web part id in an if statement but i'm not sure where to put it. the web part id that i want to run the js link file is  `" DCE7572D-9439-479D-8DBA-F5AFCC3C67B9 "`. can i do something like:

```
if (ctx.view == '{DCE7572D-9439-479D-8DBA-F5AFCC3C67B9}') {

            //---Run JS Link file on this web part---
}
```

For my jslink code i am running a template for an accordion list view. see code below.

```
function () { 

// jQuery library is required in this sample 
// Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>'));   

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
var accordionContext = {}; 
accordionContext.Templates = {}; 

// Be careful when add the header for the template, because it's will break the default list view render 
accordionContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='accordion'>"; 
accordionContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>"; 

// Add OnPostRender event handler to add accordion click events and style 
accordionContext.OnPostRender = accordionOnPostRender; 

// This line of code tell TemplateManager that we want to change all HTML for item row render 
accordionContext.Templates.Item = accordionTemplate; 

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(accordionContext); })();


// This function provides the rendering logic
function accordionTemplate(ctx) 
{
var description = ctx.CurrentItem["Phone_Number"];
var viewID = ctx.view;

// Return whole item html 
return "<h2>" + "phone number" + "</h2><p>" + description + viewID + "</p><br/>";   } 

function accordionOnPostRender() { 

// Register event to collapse and uncollapse when click on accordion header 
$('.accordion h2').click(function () { 
    $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
}).next().hide(); 

$('.accordion h2').css('cursor', 'pointer');    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where CSR flaws
and most likely a reason why it is no longer available in modern SharePoint developments.

CSR is bound to internal fieldnames, not scoped,
so if anyone adds that field to a page it gets processed by CSR.
(*this also has a benefit... you do not have to use JSLink, can define CSR transformations in one global UserCustomAction ScriptLink*)

You have to do the **hardcoded** ViewID check inside every function and code the default return (for other Views you want that OOTB rendering) as well

Comment: Hi Danny, ok thanks for the reply i may just be quicker to turn on server render option for the other web parts. also by modern sharepoint developments do you mean sharepoint 2016 ?

Comment: Modern: Modern Experiences / SharePoint Framework in SPOnline which Microsoft will also release to 2016 sometime